# How to build VS 2015 solution with projects which import targets and props from nuget packages using msbuild 14?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, nuget

**The scenario**

You add a nuget package, which in turn injects `<Import .../>` statement into your csproj file which references a targets or props file from the package itself.

This works fine when building the code in Visual Studio, but fails miserably when building the same solution with msbuild.

**The root cause**

There are several. First, the logic to restore the packages is executed by the VS itself outside of the build proper. We can solve it by importing `Nuget.targets` which would run the `RestorePackage` target before the build. Check.

But the second problem is more serious. The `Import` statements importing targets/props from the packages can only be resolved after the packages are restored. Meaning restoring the packages cannot be part of the build. It must happen before the msbuild is given the solution to build. Yes, Visual Studio does it already, but I do not use Visual Studio on my Gated Check-In or CI server. I need it to work with msbuild.

**What one can do?**

As far as I understand, I need to be able to run the same logic VS does only on the command line. I.e. identify the packages and restore them before running msbuild. But devil is in details. Cannot be I am the first one to face this problem.

How do you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in this blog post - http://sedodream.com/2013/06/06/HowToSimplifyShippingBuildUpdatesInANuGetPackage.aspx

Following this blog I have created `before.MySolutionName.sln.targets` file with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="Restore">
  <Target Name="Restore" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Exec Command=".nuget\nuget.exe restore $(MSBuildProjectName)" LogStandardErrorAsError="true" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Now all the packages in the solution are restored before the build.

Thank you, Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi.